# How to get a text from a Toast object

Tags: android, toast

I have a toast shown up, then I store the `Toast` object somewhere and later I need to get a text which was shown. But looking into [APIs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) I don't see a method to retrieve this info. Please advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need it and don't want to subclass or store string separately:

```
        Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Hellow World!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        myToast.show();

        //Now the statement below gets the text displayed
        String displayedText = ((TextView)((LinearLayout)myToast.getView()).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't store the `Toast` object, since it is largely useless to you. Store the string instead.

Comment: I need to store the Toast object for my unit tests where I check it was really shown.

Comment: @silk: I fail to see how you can "check it was really shown". Regardless, if you feel that you want to hold onto the `Toast` object, go ahead, but you will need to hold onto the message as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you want,

But just store your toast string in `R.string` file and display it by using

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.toastString);
```

Also use this later in your application when you need..

(The code posted is just for example).

Answer (score 0):

Declare one private variable in the class, before you shown up the toast assign the text value to this private variable, later you can use this variable any where in the class

Answer (score 0):

you should Take a Static variable and store Toast string in that. Show that object in Toast. 
You can also test that object.